# notify.js options are not working

Tags: javascript, notifyjs

I have the following code on my document.ready

```
$.notify("Your class starts in 15min", "info", {
  clickToHide: false,
  autoHide: false,
  globalPosition: 'top center'
});
```

but nothing happen, I only get the text and the info type, but autohide and globalposition it's not working.

What I'm doing wrong.

thanks for your helps

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1x2zt9w/2/) with your given information and everything works fine when you use

```
$.notify("Your class starts in 15min", {
  className:'info',
  clickToHide: false,
  autoHide: false,
  globalPosition: 'top right'
});
```

The problem was that you used the style information ('info') as the second parameter within the constructor, which actually expects an object of options `$.notify( string|object, [ options ])`.

Please note that I used jQuery 2.1.0 and notifyJS v0.3.1.

Comment: Thanks but it's not working, as you can see on the jsFiddle the notification is on top right and is autohiding, but my code said, autohide false and globalposition top center :(

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I will look into that. In your question you stated that 'nothing happens', which is why I made those assumptions.

Comment: that's right, let me edit the question. Thanks anyway